# what is an XQuery to import module namespace in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic-9

What is an XQuery to import module namespace in MarkLogic? How do you bind the namespace to the prefix `admin`?

```
import module namespace admin="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
```

I tried it this way but getting error.

```
ServerEvaluationCall forestDataDirCall = 
  client
   .newServerEval()
   .xquery("xquery version \"1.0-ml\";\r\n" + 
           "xdmp:with-namespaces(admin,http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply putting in the import statement as-is yet? Just use what you would use in Query Console with the exception of escaping quotes and line-ends of course..

Answer (score 0):

The import statement that you referenced does two things:

1. declares the namespace "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" bound to the `admin` namespace-prefix
2. imports the "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy" library module that is bound to that `admin` namespace, so that it's functions can be used and referenced by the `admin` prefix.

You can also simply declare a namespace and bind it to a namespace-prefix

```
declare namespace admin="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin";
```

However, then you would not have those library functions available to be used.

It appears that this question is related to one of your other questions. In order to eval code using admin functions, you need to include the import statement in the XQuery that you want to evaluate:

```
ServerEvaluationCall forestDataDirCall = client.newServerEval()
  .xquery('import module namespace admin="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy"; admin:forest-get-data-directory(admin:get-configuration(), admin:forest-get-id(admin:get-configuration(), "' + forestName +'"))');
```

Comment: I used Above query but I am getting error Invalid character constant error.

Comment: ServerEvaluationCall forestDataDirCall = client.newServerEval()
           .xquery('import module namespace admin="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy"; admin:forest-get-data-directory(admin:get-configuration(), admin:forest-get-id(admin:get-configuration(),"' + forestName +'"))');